# How can a LABEL Directive have no storage allocated to itself?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

In the book assembly language by kip irvine he talks about LABEL directives and said the following statement

""
In the following example, we declare
a label just before val32 named val16 and give it a WORD attribute:

```
.data
val16 LABEL WORD
val32 DWORD 12345678h
.code
mov ax,val16 ; AX = 5678h
mov dx,[val16+2] ; DX = 1234h
```

val16 is an alias for the same storage location as val32. The LABEL directive itself allocates no storage.
""

My question is how can val16 be the same as val32?  Where is val16 stored then?

I am confused about this?

Answer (score 4):

Think of a label as just a name you make up to use as an address holder.

Beginners often misunderstand directives because they fail to make the distinctions between directives and instructions.

Directive are used by your assembler(or compilers in C) and linkers as a sort of "shorthand notation or  instructions"  to be used to generate the final set of instructions for the CPU.

In your above  example if you read the last sentence in the book (before the code) Kip states

> A common use of LABEL is to provide an alternative name and size
>   attribute for the variable declared ***next* in the data segment**. In the
>   following example, we declare a label just before val32 named val16
>   and give it a WORD attribute:

I have highlighted the key bit of text you need to understand (notice the emphasis on the word NEXT). So in the data segment  you had something like this

```
.data
val16 LABEL WORD
val32 DWORD 12345678h
```

When you assemble the program MASM reads " val16 LABEL WORD" and says

"Hey I can see the directive "LABEL" on this line so that means he wants me to remember the address of the **NEXT** variable to be declared (in this case val32) and the **alias** he wants to give this address I have to remember is val16 and  the size of val16 is WORD"

When assembling and linking your code to produce the final executable,  whenever it sees  val16 it will just replace it with the address of Val32, so you see it consumes no storage.

SO you see the val16 is nothing more than an alias for an address and the linker simply replace it with the real address whenever it encounter it in the code as for example in your code line 
mov ax, val16   above.

And just in case any newbie is wondering why Why wasn’t 1234h moved into AX....

Kip answers that about 2 pages  before the above example :

> Why wasn’t 1234h moved into AX? x86 processors use the little endian
>   storage format in which the low-order byte is stored at the variable’s
>   starting address

Here is a picture to help you visualize it :

[image: LABELS in colour!]

Comment: Exactly, it takes up storage in the assembler while it assembles the code since it needs to remember what it means.  However, the final generated binary only has one addressable value `val32`.  Said another way, you can't store anything in `val16` without overwriting what's in `val32`.

Answer (score 1):

The label just creates a symbolic name. It uses the same storage space as the following declaration.

With the label you also specify a type (word). So in this case, val16 overlaps val32 and actually refers to the first word of the dword in val32.